# Dynamic values in Knockout template binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

For example i have such template and i want to calculate some values dynamically based on current $index

```
    <div class="cond" title="Click to flip">
        <div class="condFlip" data-bind="attr: {id: Id }, click: viewModel.setClick">               
            <div class="piece-all piece" data-bind="attr: {style: background-position: viewModel.getValue($index)  viewModel.getValue($index) }"></div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    viewModel = {
        flips: ko.observableArray([]),      

        setClick: function (data, e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //doing things
        },

        getValue: function (data, e) {
            return //get my value
        }        
    };    

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

so how can i use function viewModel.getValue in model binding? is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call functions that return strings in the way that you are doing it, but your format is slightly off.  Here are a few tips:

- you can use the `style` binding rather than the `attr` binding, as it will add/remove the individual styling rather than replace the entire style attribute (maybe not important for your case).
- in the binding string, `background-position` is an invalid property name in the object literal that you are creating to specify your bindings.  You need to either use `"background-position"` in quotes or the name that you can use in JavaScript `backgroundPosition`
- you would either want your `getValue` function to return the full string like `15px 30px` or build it in the binding like:  `getValue($index) + ' ' + getValue($index)`
- `$index` is an observable, so you will need to call it as a function to get its value, when you are processing it in your function.

So, your binding might look like:

```
<i class="icon-blah" data-bind="style: { backgroundPosition: viewModel.getValue($index) + ' ' + viewModel.getValue($index) }"></i>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BAVZa/